# undo editing standard process in Powerapps

Tags: process, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, powerapps, dynamics-365

I'm using PowerApps with Dynamics 365. While I was practicing on Powerapps I had edited the "Lead to Opportunity" process and deleted one of the stages, I thought that the effect of deletion will be only on my app and solution, but I was surprised that the stage disappeared also from Sales hub and Sales team member apps too.

Please, what can I do to return the original process?

Comment: PowerApps connects directy to your data source. If you send a delete command in PowerApps to your datasource, the item will be deleted in your datasource. You're going to need to "undelete" the item from Dynamics (if possible).

Comment: Any followup questions?

Answer (score 0):

If you just need that OOB BPF, try exporting in a solution from another environment and import into your affected organization. That should solve the problem.

There is no soft delete, once saved and published - it overwrites, that being said - take a backup in a solution (zip file) and keep it aside, else do “save as” before doing any customization. Even better, keep a lower environment for POC, R&D without disturbing your Prod replica Dev environment.